# How to login app by Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have set facebook authentication up on Microsoft Azure.
Now I want to use it in Xamarin android. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article that talks about authenticating users with azure mobile apps on xamarin forms.  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/azure/